# Can every usage of While be changed into NestWhile?

Tags: programming, evaluation, functional-style

OK, I think this problem is more close to philosophy. :P

I've some idea now. But I'm not sure whether it's correct.
For the purpose of convenience, I will use some C-like code instead of *Mathematica*'s.

A `While` loop is something like:

```
i=0; // some initialize of variable i
While(test of variable i)   // such like i<10 or i^3<90, etc.
{
   // involving doing something which has nothing to do with i (e.g. Print["*"])
   // or involving taking i as an argument of another function, such like Sin[i]
   // or involving re-assign some value to i, such like i=i+7
}
Print[i] // after doing such evaluations, we want to get the final value of i
```

The first and second line surrounded in while is not really a problem for `NestWhile`.
It is just because `NestWhile` is `NestWhile[f, expr, test]`,
one can write `(Print["*"]; Sin[#] + 1 &)` in the place of `f`, doing the same thing you want when you're dealing with `While`.

However, when you want to re-assign `expr` in `NestWhile`, No, you cannot.
`i = 0; NestWhile[# = # + 1 &, i, # < 70 &]` is not what you want. (The `i` is immediately change into 0 before you would want to do `i = i+1`)

And just because of this simple difference between `While` and `NestWhile`,
I doubt that EVERY `While`-code can change into `NestWhile`-code.

Comment: In my experience, While is very easy to compile, but NestWhile is not.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Since there is a newer `FunctionCompile` now, is this still true in V13?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking the question at face value, I think the answer is yes. A `While` loop

```
While[test, body]
```

evaluates *test* then *body* until *test* fails to give `True`. This can be implemented in `NestWhile` by putting *test* and *body* into `Function`s:

```
NestWhile[body &, Null, test &]
```

For example the following both do the same thing:

```
i = 0; While[i < 10, i++];
i = 0; NestWhile[(i++) &, Null, (i < 10) &];
```

I don't think this is what you are after though. In the question you describe a restricted subset of `While` loops in which *body* consists of "doing stuff with some variable `i`" and *test* consists of "a function of `i`". The question, I think, is whether such `While` loops can be converted to `NestWhile` with the variable `i` used as the `expr` (i.e. second argument) in `NestList`.

As you pointed out, this is not easily done. Here is a possible approach using `Hold` to prevent unwanted evaluations:

```
i = 0;
NestWhile[((Increment @@ #); #) &, Hold[i], ReleaseHold[#] < 10 &]
```

This is pretty horrible. Not only do we have to jump through hoops to evaluate `i++` without prematurely evaluating `i`, the iterated function now takes `Hold[i]` as input and returns the same `Hold[i]` as output. The whole principle of functional iteration has been murdered just to allow us to (awkwardly) manipulate the global symbol `i` as a side effect.

In summary the answer is yes, you *can* change every usage of `While` into `NestWhile`, **but you shouldn't**. `NestWhile`'s purpose is to implement functional iteration - don't think of it as a special case of `While`, think of it as a special case of `Nest`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to change While to NestWhile is to incorporate variable increments, such as i++, as part the repeated function application. The idea of incorporating increments is similar to what Simon Woods proposed.

You can go a step further and roll the initialisation into Nestwhile as well--closer in spirit perhaps to a functional version.

**Example for Fibonacci numbers:**

The function fib generates the k-th fibonacci number:

```
fib[k_] := Nest[{#[[2]], #[[1]] + #[[2]]} &, {0, 1}, k][[2]]
```

The following While-code produces the list of fibonacci numbers valued strictly below 10:

```
n = 0;
fibList = {};
While[fib[n] < 10, fibList = Join[fibList, {fib[n]}]; n++]
fibList
```

output: {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8}

Compare this with a NestWhile implementation producing the same output:

```
NestWhile[{Join[#[[1]], {fib[#[[2]]]}], #[[2]] + 1} &, {{}, 0}, 
  fib[#[[2]]] < 10 &][[1]]
```

The initialisation value is `{{ },0}`

The nested function is `Join[#[[1]], {fib[#[[2]]]}], #[[2]] + 1} &`

Comment: (+1) I would describe the conversion from `While[]` to `NestWhile[]` in terms "state variables," but that's to do with my background which is not CS: `NestWhile[
  Apply@Function[
    statevariables, body
    ],
  initialvalues,
  Apply@Function[
    statevariables, test
    ]] // First`. For instance, in your example `statevariables` becomes `{fibList, n}` and `body` becomes `{Join[fibList, {fib[n]}], n + 1}`; and `test` becomes `fib[n] < 10`. One could also do a more direct translation like this: `Block[
  statevariables,
  statevariables = #;
  whilebody;
  statevariables
  ] &`