# How to replace While construct to NestWhile(functional-style) correctly?

Tags: programming, functional-style

Recently,I find the program of *@J.M.* about 
[Get a "step-by-step" evaluation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica]) 
is a very useful example for learning *Mathematica* programming.

In the function **`WalkD`**,I see the construct of **`While`**(it is common in procedural programming paradigm).I know *Mathematica*'s functional programming paradigm is very elegent,so I'd like to use the function **`NestWhile`** to rewrite the the construct of **`While`**.

#### Origin program:

```
WalkD[f_, x_] := Module[{derivative, oldderivative, k}, 
    derivative = d[f, x]; displayStart[derivative];

   (*First While construct*)
    While[! FreeQ[derivative, d],
        oldderivative = derivative; k = 0;

        (*Second while construct*)
        While[oldderivative == derivative,
                  k++;
                  derivative = derivative /. 
                          ToExpression[StringReplace[$RuleNames[[k]], " " -> ""]]];
        displayDerivative[derivative, k]];
    D[f, x]]
```

#### My trial to rewrite the inner `While` construct

```
WalkDRewrite[f_, x_] :=
 Module[
  {derivative, oldderivative, k},
   derivative = d[f, x];
   displayStart[derivative];

 While[! FreeQ[derivative, d],
  oldderivative = derivative;
  k = 0;

 (*begin to rewrite*)
 NestWhile[
   CompoundExpression[#2++,
     #1 = #1 /. ToExpression[StringReplace[$RuleNames[[k]], " " -> ""]]] &,
   Sequence[derivative, k],
   oldderivative != derivative
 ]
 (*end *)

  displayDerivative[derivative, k]
 ];
 D[f, x]
]
```

However,I failed after debugging all morning.

### Question:

Is it possible to use `NestWhile` to replace `While`?Thanks sincerely!

Comment: Try using `{derivative,k}` in place of `Sequence[derivative,k]` **and** either (1) use `Apply` with your `CompoundExpression[...]&`, i.e., `CompoundExpression[...]&@@#&`, or (2) change `#1` and `#2` to `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]`, respectively.

Comment: @kguler,thanks:),there is no warning information appeared with your suggestion.However,I feel this program is stuck in a vicious circle.Namely,it cannot achieve correct result.

Comment: related: [Can every usage of While be changed into NestWhile?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57025/18476)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the inner loop:

```
While[oldderivative == derivative,
          k++;
          derivative = derivative /. 
                  ToExpression[StringReplace[$RuleNames[[k]], " " -> ""]]];
```

The first observation is that you have *two* variables which you change in the original `While` loop, `derivative` and `k`, but `NestWhile` supports only one function argument. But that is easily solved by passing a list containing those two variables.

The test function therefore is easy:

```
#[[1]] == oldderivative &
```

The actual evaluation function gives the new values as function of the old values. Note that `#[[2]]` is the *old* value of `k`, therefore an extra `+1` is needed:

```
{ #[[1]] /. ToExpression[StringReplace[$RuleNames[[ #[[2]]+1 ]], " " -> ""]],
  #[[2]]+1 }&
```

And the initial values are, of course, `derivative` and `0`.

Now we already see that the expressions get quite complicated, therefore we should make use of some function definitions, which also allows to make the code more readable through pattern matching. The inner loop body function makes a great candidate for this:

```
derivativeReplace[{derivative_, k_}] :=
   { derivative /. ToExpression[StringReplace[$RuleNames[[k+1]], " " -> ""]],
     k+1 }
```

Therefore the inner loop should look like this:

```
{derivative, k} =
  NestWhile[derivativeReplace, {derivative, 0}, #[[1]] == oldderivative &]
```

And thus the outer loop now is

```
While[! FreeQ[derivative, d],
    oldderivative = derivative;

    {derivative, k} =
      NestWhile[derivativeReplace, {derivative, 0},#[[1]] == oldderivative &]
    displayDerivative[derivative, k]];
```

Now the first thing you see is that `derivative` is no longer changed before `NestList` returns, therefore we can completely get rid of `oldderivative`:

```
While[! FreeQ[derivative, d],
    {derivative, k} =
      NestWhile[derivativeReplace, {derivative, 0}, #[[1]] == derivative &];
    displayDerivative[derivative, k]];
```

Note that `k` is only needed for `displayDerivative`, and not further used. To isolate the reassignment of `derivative` (which we need to do to replace the outer loop), we can use an anonymous helper function:

```
While[! FreeQ[derivative, d],
  derivative = Function[{deriv, k},
                        displayDerivative[deriv, k]; deriv] @@
      NestWhile[derivativeReplace, {derivative, 0}, #[[1]] == derivative &]];
```

Now the outer loop is in the perfect form for translation into `NestWhile`:

```
NestWhile[
  Function[derivative,
    Function[{deriv, k}, displayDerivative[deriv, k]; deriv] @@
      NestWhile[derivativeReplace, {derivative, 0}, #[[1]] == derivative &]],
        derivative, ! FreeQ[#, d]&];
```

Note that I ignore the return value of the outer `NestWhile` since `derivative` is no longer used after the rule. The complete function replacement therefore reads:

```
derivativeReplace[{derivative_, k_}] :=
   { derivative /. ToExpression[StringReplace[$RuleNames[[k+1]], " " -> ""]],
     k+1 }

WalkDReplacement[f_, x_] := Module[{derivative}, 
  derivative = d[f, x]; displayStart[derivative];

  NestWhile[
    Function[derivative,
      Function[{deriv, k}, displayDerivative[deriv, k]; deriv] @@
        NestWhile[derivativeReplace, {derivative, 0}, #[[1]] == derivative &]],
        derivative, ! FreeQ[#, d]&];

  D[f, x]]
```

Comment: ,Thanks! Dear celtschk, I have modified some mistakes in your answer and debug the program of the inner `While` construct. However, I cannot understand the outer `While` construct that you rewrite, namely,I cannot debug it. Lastly, by this question, I feel that it is hard to rewrite the `While` construct to `NestWhile` construct sometimes, as well as it is easy to understand `While`construct sometimes.

Comment: I've now fixed the error in my code; my tests indicate it works now correctly. The error was rather stupid: I forgot to supply the initial argument and test function to `NestWhile`, and to close the remaining open function argument brackets.

Comment: @Tangshutao: Anyway, I forgot: thank you for correcting my other mistakes (and I also forgot the @-attribution so you get notified).

Comment: I think this shows why I *didn't* try to use `NestWhile[]` in that routine. :)